# Asterisk - Auto Dial another extension

Tags: asterisk

I am looking for some info on configuring auto routing in Asterisk for this specific case:

I have one employee who has 2 phones, 1 at the office and 1 at home, each having separate extensions numbers.

I was looking to know if I can have it when this worker is in the office, he uses his normal extension, say for this case its 20. The following day he will be working from home and will now be on extension 21.

I can map extension 20 to this remote **device** through some hotkey so instead of call 21, I actually call 20 and he will get the call?

Thanks in advance
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

> `20 => {
>
>   Dial(SIP/20,15);
>
>   Dial(SIP/20&SIP/21,35);
>
>   }`
>
> `21 => {
>
>   Dial(SIP/21,15);
>
>   Dial(SIP/20&SIP/21,35);
>
>   }`

This way when you dial ext 20 it rings 20 for 15 seconds and then 20 and 21 for 35 seconds! The same for ext 21!